# When launcher at bottom, mouse click in DASH won't start app

Tags: unity, mouse, launcher, icons, unity-dash

Ubuntu 16.04

I used Unity Tweak tool to move launcher to bottom of main monitor.

I pressed the Super key that brings up the Dash. I can type in that window to filter the app icons as normal. I can move around with arrow keys and press enter to start an app. But I cannot mouse click on any app and have it start.

I went back into Unity Tweak and set launcher position to left instead of bottom. When it is set to left, it works as expected... ie: mouse click starts the app I clicked on.

I would really like to be able to have launcher at the bottom and DASH working again with mouse clicks if possible.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A little more investigation, it's as if the dash window is behind the other windows.  That is to say, when I click an icon the window that is displaying behind the dash actually receives the click and not the icon in dash.  Anybody?

Comment: I found another weirdness... I have multiple monitors (four actually)... when activating the dash on the top left monitor, it works as normal.

My monitors are arranged as such... top left is a 1920x1080, directly beneath that is another 1920x1080.  To the right of that one is a 3840x2160 and to the right of that one is another 3840x2160.  The X and Y positions of these are sort of odd with the mixture of resolution sizes and all.  `~/.config/monitors.xml` was a tough one to get correct. Think maybe something in there is the cause?

Comment: I am also having the same issue. My monitors are vertically stacked and centered.

Answer (score 1):

My two smaller monitors were the culprit.

The first photo is how I prefer my displays, but it causes Dash to lose its mind.

The second photo shows the display configuration that allows Dash to react to the mouse clicks as normal.

I hope this helps someone out there, although I feel like I am talking to myself.  :)

[image: non-working display configuration]
[image: working display configuration]